# How do you find x,y coordinate of based on the edge of a circle by looking at my mouse cursor

Tags: javascript, math, processing, trigonometry, p5.js

I'm trying to find x,y coordinate based on trigonometry within the edge of a circle according to my mouse position.

[image]

As you can see from the gif image, as your mouse move, the tip of the triangle is always pointing at the edge of the circle as my mouse is moving around the ellipse.

I'm using P5.js and I wish to know how to write this and appreciate if you can walk me through trigonometry behind this, so I can leverage this knowledge and try out more types of visual programming ideas that are in my head.

Comment: You talk about ellipses, but the image shows a circle. Do you need a circle (special case of an ellipsis), or the more general, but also more complex general case?

Comment: Updated the thread, I'm talking about a single circle for now.

Comment: Ah, turns out, ellipse isn't that much more difficult https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Ellipse-LineIntersection.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Compute the vector form the center of the circle (`cx`, `cy`) to the mouse position ([`mouseX`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/mouseX), [`mouseY`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/mouseY)).  Use [`p5.Vector`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5.Vector) respectively [`createVector()`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/createVector) to represent the vector and change the magnitude of the vector to the `radius` of the circle by [`setMag()`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5.Vector/setMag):

```js
let v = createVector(mouseX - cx, mouseY - cy).setMag(radius);
let px = v.x + cx;
let py = v.y + cy;
```

respectively

```js
let cpt = createVector(cx, cy);
let pt = createVector(mouseX, mouseY).sub(cpt).setMag(radius).add(cpt);
let px = pt.x;
let py = pt.y;
```

Comment: Awesome, this works great! I will try to understand this ! cheers